# solr - getting results that starts with usephrase

Tags: solr

I have the following document in solr

```
<doc>
  <str name="PackageName">A lot of devices on one drawing </str>
  ...
```

the schema defines PackageName as

```
<field name="PackageName" type="text_general_edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

where

```
<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Now, I want to set a query that when a user querys

```
 http://...:8983/solr/vault/select?q=PackageName:"A lot"
```

It will return but

```
 http://...:8983/solr/vault/select?q=PackageName:"B lot"
```

will not return 
and

currently

```
 http://...:8983/solr/vault/select?q=PackageName:B lot
```

and

```
 http://...:8983/solr/vault/select?q=PackageName:A lot
```

retun the document, and surrounding it with " doesnt return anything in both cases.
How can I change my query?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EdgeNGramFilterFactory will delete the token which is less the size defined for minGramSize which is defined as 2 in your case. Check [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5152)
Also when you query `packageName:"A Lot"` the search terms are searched on the field packageName.
However, when you search `packageName:A Lot` Solr will search as `packageName:a defaultField:lot` which seems to be matching your case.